# Unique bounding rectangle.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, functional-analysis

Let $K\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be compact and connected.

Then we can always find rectangles that bound $K$. Moreover, we can find the minimum-area such a bounding rectangle could have.

My question is this: Is it true that if there are two or more minimum-area bounding rectangles, then those rectangles are squares?

Any pointing to the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Consider an equilateral triangle.

Comment: @ChristianSykes Your counter-example stands. The only missing step is that [one side of the minimum-area rectangle must be collinear with an edge of the enclosed polygon](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=360919).

Comment: @dxiv I deleted my comment expressing uncertainty mere seconds before you posted your own comment, but thank you for the reassurance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K$ is an acute triangle, then each side of $K$ is also the side of a minimal bounding rectangle whose area is twice the area of $K$. Since $K$ is acute, none of these rectangles are square.

For details on showing that these rectangles are in fact minimal, see:
[Minimal-area rectangle, bounding (covering) an acute triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879520/minimal-area-rectangle-bounding-covering-an-acute-triangle)